# Variable courseTitle was never mutated

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Guys I get this error

> Variable courseTitle was never mutated

while trying to use the '**dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier**'.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    let devCourses = [("iOS App Dev with Swift Essential Training","Simon Allardice"),
        ("iOS 8 SDK New Features","Lee Brimelow"),
        ("Data Visualization with D3.js","Ray Villalobos"),
        ("Swift Essential Training","Simon Allardice"),
        ("Up and Running with AngularJS","Ray Villalobos"),
        ("MySQL Essential Training","Bill Weinman"),
        ("Building Adaptive Android Apps with Fragments","David Gassner"),
        ("Advanced Unity 3D Game Programming","Michael House"),
        ("Up and Running with Ubuntu Desktop Linux","Scott Simpson"),
        ("Up and Running with C","Dan Gookin")]


    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return devCourses.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            var (courseTitle, courseAuthor) = devCourses[indexPath.row]

            cell.textLabel?.text = courseTitle
            return cell

        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Read also the second part of the warning, that's the *idea*

Comment: it says: Variable 'courseAuthor' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it

Comment: That's a new warning, I meant the original warning mentioned in your question. Anyhow the compiler tries always to give reasonable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You are allowing the courseTitle to be changed. Change the var to a let:

```
let (courseTitle, courseAuthor) = devCourses[indexPath.row]
```

With Swift development its a good idea to always use let by default, and then only change to a var if you need to make changes.

Comment: i get a SIGABRT error after compile when i do that .

Comment: `let (courseTitle, _) = devCourses[indexPath.row]` it's better

Comment: It gives a SIGABRT error when change it to "_" as well.

Comment: If you comment out the line where you set the cell text, do you still get this SIGABRT error?

Comment: Yes I do. if this is what you meant: " //cell.textLabel?.text = courseTitle"

Answer (score 0):

Change var to let since you are not mutating the value of the courseTitle or courseAuthor.

```
let courseInfo = devCourses[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = courseInfo.0
```

Comment: But I'm trying to pass 2 arguments(courseAuthor and courseTitles). Yours contains one argument. Or am i missing something?

Comment: Ah! I see what you did there; makes sense as it'd pass both constants. But isn't there a way to pass the two?

Comment: What do you mean by pass the two? Do you mean to concatenate both strings in the tuple?

Comment: Yeah. To pass the two strings in instead of one.

Comment: you can concatenate both strings with courseInfo.0 + courseInfo.1